# How to append command to add_custom_target in CMake

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have a custom target in CMake for unit tests like the below

```
 add_custom_target(
      test
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ATest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DTest)
```

but I want to add an additional test to the target based on whether an external dependency is found. Currently, I did it with

```
if(EXTERNAL_FOUND)
  add_custom_target(
      test
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ATest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ETest)
else()
  add_custom_target(
      test
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ATest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DTest)
endif()
```

This is not very elegant and it quickly becomes unmanageable when there are multiple conditions. Is there something like append to custom target so we can write the below instead?

```
add_custom_target(
      test
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ATest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DTest)

if(EXTERNAL_FOUND)
  # I can't seem to find something like this
  append_custom_target(test COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ETest)
else()
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Or is there a better way to do this?" -> Use CTest (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) and use it as dependency to your target. With the custom command you can `APPEND` commands with same `OUTPUT`:

```
add_custom_target(
    test
    DEPENDS test-cmd
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT test-cmd
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "ATest"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "BTest"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "CTest"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "DTest"
)
if(EXTERNAL_FOUND)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT test-cmd APPEND
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "ETest"
    )
endif()

# test-cmd is not actually generated so set it to symbolic
set_source_files_properties(test-cmd PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC "true")
```

See [SYMBOLIC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SYMBOLIC.html) for the artifical source file property.